# error: failed in converting 1st keyword `w' of dfitpack.fpcurf0 to C/Fortran array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I the following error when using the Scipy `UnivariateSpline` function:

```
0-th dimension must be 100 but got 0 (not defined).                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                              
  File "/Users/phil/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py", line 181, in __init__                     
    xb=bbox[0],xe=bbox[1],s=s)                                                                                                     
dfitpack.error: failed in converting 1st keyword `w' of dfitpack.fpcurf0 to C/Fortran array
```

A code example to recreate this is:

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                             
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline                                                                                 
X = np.arange(0, 100)                                                                                                          
Y = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100)                                                                                        
UnivariateSpline(X, Y, .1)
```

I have reshaped X and Y so they are have two dimensions e.g `X.reshape(100, 1)` and have also converted to floats e.g. `X.astype(float)`

Running on Mac OSX, Anaconda Python `2.7.12` and Scipy `0.18.1`

Comment: Why do you have the third argument `0.1` in the call `UnivariateSpline(X, Y, .1)`?  Please read [the docstring of `UnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html), and note that if the third argument, `w`, is given, it must be an array with the same length as `x` and `y`.

Comment: Ahhh thanks, it is meant to be s=.1. I do this and it works!